# software able to read the hardware and install drivers

Tags: windows-7, drivers

I can't remember how is called that software that is able to understand what is your hardware and automatically install drivers. It was an ISO image with the software and a lot of drivers.

It's for Windows.

Comment: There was one in beta for a while (2008) called DriverGeek, but it looks like it is no longer available.

Comment: There are many out there but most do not work as well as Windows Update or finding them yourself and installing. Here is one...http://www.soluto.com/

Comment: Drivermax is another one that does he job, but only by online way, and with 2 drivers by day limitation :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this list: http://technologytosoftware.com/useful-software-search-missing-windows-driver.html

If it isn't there we can keep looking.

Comment: first of al +1 for the list, but the software I was looking for, since it had drivers in the iso, could allow to install driver offline...

Comment: My bad, forgot about the ISO part. Did you mean this: http://forum.egypt.com/enforum/software-programs-f194/100-000-universal-windows-drivers-iso-october-updated-6063.html

Comment: not bad but it's an old update. We're getting closer though.

Comment: which version of windows are you running?

Comment: it's windows seven

Comment: This one is from Microsoft: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=36a2630f-5d56-43b5-b996-7633f2ec14ff